# Не удается получить имя пользователя в C# с помощью WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

Я пишу сервис Windows на C#. В нем мне нужно получить имя пользователя, который сейчас активен. Различные UserName и WindowsIdentiy возращают System, так как сервис запускается системой, но мне нужен тот пользователь, в котором я нахожусь.

Сейчас я получаю его с помощью WMI следующим образом:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
ret = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

На локальной машине всё хорошо получается, но, когда к моей машине кто-то подключается удаленно по RDP и авторизуется на ней, имя этого пользователя таким образом получить(локально на моей машине) не удается, возращается пустая строка. В принципе необязательно с помощью WMI, главное чтобы однозначно определялось имя пользователя.

Answer (score -1):

А каким образом к вам подключаются? Через RDP или Telnet?
Я делал тоже самое когда-то и вот примерный вариант моего кода:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + host + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT *FROM " + _searchClass[bred_sobachiy]);
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(400);
                    temp = obj.GetPropertyValue(param[bred_sobachiy]).ToString();
                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(TODO));
                    if (bred_sobachiy == _searchClass.Length - 1)
                    {
                        active_connection.Text = ip_cache.Substring(ip_cache.IndexOf(":") + 2) + ": успешно";
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Может он вам будет полезным.

Comment: Бред какой-то.. Если верить именам переменных, то собачий))

Comment: Знающий сам додумается в чем тут прикол. Я не обязан еще и каждую переменную здесь вам растолковывать.
Для наглядности лишь скажу, что:
_searchClass[] - это строковый массив, который хранит в себе определенные классы.
Например: string[] _searchClass = { "Win32_ComputerSystem", "Win32_OperatingSystem" ......... };
bred_sobachiy - это целочисленная переменная изначально равная 0. Создавал для подсчета и для передвижения по массиву строки, точнее по классам.
Ну и param: string[] param = { "UserName"..}. У меня в нем несколько параметров хранится, поэтому так сокращенно написал.

Comment: @StarStrit Конечно не обязан, но чем более подробный ответ, тем более он полезен спрашивающему, а слишком короткие и "зашифрованные" ответы модераторы и снести могут...

Comment: @StarStrit По RDP. 
И мой сервис стоит на том компьютере, к которому подключаются по RDP, то есть мне нужно получить не удаленное имя пользователя, а то, которое сейчас на моем компьютере.
И проблема в том, что в таблице Win32_ComputerSystem в таком случае поле UserName пустое.
Еще мне необязательно по WMI, можно в принципе любым другим способом, главное чтобы имя пользователя однозначно определялось на том компьютере, на котором стоит сервис.

Comment: @Dmitriy, согласен - исправлюсь )

Comment: @Pologitko, понял. Я сам недавно начал работать с WMI и пока еще не вникал в такие подробности. Сам даже и не задумывался почему так происходит... Извините )

Comment: @Qwertiy, можешь проголосовать за удаление данного ответа - если не устраивает...

Comment: @StarStrit, я никак на этом ответе не голосовал. Если хочешь его удалить, это можно сделать и самостоятельно.